# Trying to determine Date Difference in PHP/MySQL, and pass to Datatable

Tags: php, mysql, date, datatable

I have an SQL table (events) where I have a DATE field (eventdate).
I have an instance of Datatables, where I would like to show the difference between today's date and eventdate.

At the most basic level, I was trying to do this:

```
nestedData[] = date_diff(date("Y-m-d"), $row['eventdate']);
```

My thinking is that I'm passing a today's date and eventdate to the date_diff function, and the result would be added to nestedData[].  When I do that, I get an error on the Datatable page.

I also tried:

```
nestedData[] = date_diff(date_create(date("Y-m-d")), $row['eventdate'];
```

I thought that I might need to create a date instance, and that might be the issue.  No change.

Then I tried just testing sending dates back to the datatables, to see what was happening.

```
$today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$todayii = $today->format('Y-m-d');

nestedData[] = $todayii;
```

When I use that, I am correctly getting today's date (ccyy-mm-dd) appearing in my datatable.

If I change that to:

```
$today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));

nestedData[] = $today;
```

Instead of today's date, the datatable field is populated with [object Object]

I guess ultimately my question is: What do I need to pass to date_diff() to get that value back?  Should I be passing a date_create() object?  Do I need to try date_create() on the eventdate value?

I tried:

```
$nestedData[] = date_diff(date_create(date('Y-m-d')), date_create($row["eventdate"]));
```

but that also returned [object Object]

I'm sure this is something really simple, but I've been looking at it so long and tried so many things, I'm not sure what to try next.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, but I was finally able to make this do what I was looking for.

```
$d1 = new datetime($row["eventdate"]);
$d2 = new datetime(date('Y-m-d'));
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);
$iDays = $interval->days;
$nestedData[] = $iDays;
```

While not a big deal, the last thing I need to figure out here is how to get a negative sign when $d1 (eventdate) is in the past.  Probably won't be too difficult to resolve, and not critical to what I'm doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['eventdate']);
$databasedate= date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);

$currentserverdate=date('d-m-Y')

nestedData[] = date_diff($currentserverdate, $databasedate);
```

Comment: I tried making the adjustments you suggested, but am still not getting a valid value passed back.  If I set nestedData[] = $currentserverdate, or nestedData[] = $databasedate, either of them do get passed back and populated in the table.  But if I set nestedData[] = date_diff($currentserverdate, $databasedate), then I get the same "Loading ..." </br> "No data found on server" (which is my default error text) message.  It's like the date_diff() doesn't like the dates that are being passed into it.